# fatal exception : thread 8, java.nullpointerexception

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-cursor, encoder

when I try running the application I found the error message in logcat, `NullPointerException`. Where the code which make this error is show below. The str is get from another class which is call `MD5encoder`. The code show below as well. the string `md 5 = MD5Encoder.encode(str)` and cursor is from the `mainActiviry`. `MD5encoder` is another class of a java file where I import to `MainActivity`. I wonder is it the cursor where `md5 = ?`, new string it cant get the str or the value so it throw a `NullPointerException`. someone any idea about this ?

```
String md5 = MD5Encoder.encode(str);    
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT desc FROM datatable WHERE md5 = '?' ",new String[] { md5 });

public class MD5Encoder {

public static String encode(String source){

    String result = null;

    try {

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");

        byte[] output = md.digest(source.getBytes());

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for(int i=0;i<output.length;i++){

            String s = Integer.toHexString(0xff&output[i]);

            if(s.length()==1){
                sb.append("0"+s);
            }else{
                sb.append(s);
            }
        }
        result= sb.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` gets thrown when you access a `null` pointer. You should investigate the `stacktrace` which indicates the line where the exception happened.

For more info about the exception have a look at the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

Comment: thanks moss the problem is solve, thank you very much ! the information u given is useful !